# iOS error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite, exception

i am a new developer i am getting this error .
i tired to fix it by adding the libsqlite3.0.dylib twice and restarting the x-code .
even i added the other lib of libsqlite3.dylib but didint worked.
Error :
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writeable database file with message

```
-(void)copyDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    NSFileManager * filemanger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbpath= [self getDbPath];
    BOOL success = [filemanger fileExistsAtPath:dbpath];

    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultDBpath= [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDatabase.sqlite"];
        success = [filemanger copyItemAtPath:defaultDBpath toPath:dbpath error:&error];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writeable database file with message '@' .", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

}
-(NSString *)getDbPath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDatabase.sqlite"];
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can create a database within your application bundle - it's read-only.

Comment: You have to manually specify that you need the DataBase to be read only if you want to open it inside the apps bundle

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go, this function opens a database, and if it doesn't exist in documents, it copies it from bundle.  Did you need to create one from scratch?

```
-(BOOL) openDB: (NSString *) dbName{
    NSString *dbPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    dbPath = [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]) {

        NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];   
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:dbPath error:nil];
    }

    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))           
    {               
       NSLog(@"An error has occured opening Sqlite");  
       return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: it would be very helpful for me if assist me to create this code from scratch . // i have made those changes app delegate file and i took code reference from : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ze2Vhi48kQ&feature=channel&list=UL

Comment: the sqlite3_open command will create an empty database if it doesn't exist, in which case it will be a blank database.  So this method tries to copy a database from bundles, but if not found a blank one with that name is created.  This is intentional functionality of sqlite3_open.  If you give some more info on error or issues you are encountering, may be able to help more.